# Workbook opening on a network with "corrupt" macros

Tags: excel, vba

A colleague is trying to open an `.xlsm` book from a network folder but gets this message:

> The visual basic for applications (VBA) macros for this workbook are corrupted and have been deleted. The corruption most likely exists in the current file. To recover the macros, open up a backup copy of this file if you have one.

If they download and save the file from an e-mail then open it locally it works fine.

Other people can also open this book from the network and it works fine.

In the failing book, it appears that all objects (worksheets and modules) have been duplicated with a `1` suffix.

Searching this issue online I found several suggestions but none of them seem to fit this scenario.

Comment: It might be a `Permission` issue. If you're not the network administrator, let him give the user more access.

Comment: Ah so maybe their access to that online directory / folder is limited somewhat. Good suggestion I may have to look into that. Of course that means raising a ticket with IT which will probably take about 10 years to fulfil.

Comment: Thank goodness that you cannot execute files directly from a url! You need to know it's a dangerous "world" out there. Ransomware, phishing, trojan, info stealer, etc... You should use a cloud storage provider that can map it to a local drive/folder, then change macro to that path.

Comment: What do you mean "execute files"? - it's a company intranet file network specifically for sharing, and the location in question is already mapped to the user's PC. The VBA inside uses relative referencing but it won't even get that far because it opens "corrupt"